# Plot Pandas DF as stacked bar chart while ignoring missing values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've got a dataframe with workout logs like this:

```
>>> data
       _date  _week  Distance (km)
0 2020-10-31     44      42.220013
1 2020-10-29     44      10.054135
2 2020-10-25     43      30.103745
3 2020-10-24     43      14.135142
4 2020-10-20     43      10.471132
5 2020-10-17     42      27.164278
6 2020-10-15     42      18.511157
```

And would like to plot it as a stacked-bar chart per week, like this:

[image: Plot grouped by weeks]

**Problem 1:** I can't figure out how to *pivot* or *group by* the DF before plotting, given that it's got uneven number of workouts per week, up to 4 or 5, but sometimes none at all when I was lazy.

**Problem 2:** Optionally I'd like to sort them from longest to shortest for aesthetics, so that the longest ones are always the same colour and are at the bottom, etc. But it's nit picking :)

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a new field for `Run` using `cumcount` and `pivot` it to columns with `week` on the index:

```
df['Run'] = 'Run ' + (df.groupby('_week').cumcount() + 1).astype(str)
df = df.drop('_date', axis=1).set_index('_week').pivot(columns='Run')
df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

[image]

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks! The `cumcount()` was the key piece I was missing.